# magit and /usr/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server

Tags: emacs, magit

## emacsclient 26.1

## emacs 26.1

## Magit 20180604.958, Git 2.17.1, Emacs 26.1, gnu/linux

My emacs is configured to work in a daemon mode

when I'm trying to commit a staged file, I get this:

```
GitError! There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server
```

and inside magit process window I see this

```
  0 git … add -u .
  1 git … commit --all --no-verify
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Symbol’s function definition is void: magit-process
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

#### ~/.config/systemd/user/emacsd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor
Documentation=man:emacs(1) info:Emacs

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(progn (setq kill-emacs-hook nil) (kill emacs))"
Environment=DISPLAY=:%i
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I have the following variables

```
alias emacs='lc_collate=c emacsclient -c -n "$@"'
```

and

```
➜  frontend git:(experiment) ✗ echo $EDITOR                                           
/usr/bin/eclient

➜  frontend git:(experiment) ✗ cat /usr/bin/eclient                       
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/emacsclient -c -nw "$@"
```

#### I also get these messages

Revert buffer from file /home/dmitry/Projects/p/frontend/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG? (y or n)

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am getting a similar error all of a sudden and tried updating. I also have Emacs 26.1.

Comment: Remove `~/.emacs.d` and reinstall: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72001/8563

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading Emacs from 26 to 27. Problem was resolved after I cleaned `.emacs.d` folder (`git clean -xdf` will do the trick if configs are saved in git).